# Magento2 admin panel, open an url in new tab using window.open

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, link

Below codes opens the link in same window, how can I change it to open it in new tab?

```
if ($canModify) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Login As Customer'),
                'class' => 'login login-button',
                'on_click' => 'window.open( \'' . $this->getInvalidateTokenUrl() .
                    '\')',
                'sort_order' => 70,
            ];
        }
```

edit:

below are not working:

```
'on_click' => 'window.open( \'' . $this->getInvalidateTokenUrl() .
                    '\',\'_blank\')',
```

and

```
'on_click' => 'window.open( \'' . $this->getInvalidateTokenUrl() .
                    '\')',
                'target' => '_blank',
```

Comment: have you try with , onclick=""this.target=\'_blank\'""?

Answer (score 3):

You should add attribute `target="_blank"` to your element. Something like this I think would work:

```
if ($canModify) {
            $data = [
                'label' => __('Login As Customer'),
                'class' => 'login login-button',
                'on_click' => 'window.open( \'' . $this->getInvalidateTokenUrl() .
                    '\')',
                'sort_order' => 70,
                'target' => '_blank'  
            ];
        }
```

For example: `<div class="login login-button" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')" target="_blank">Click me</div>`.

Comment: I had tried such but it does not work

Comment: What does this code generate in frontend? Can you paste it here? Whole element...

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->addButton(
                'back', [
            'label' => __('New Tab'),
            'onclick' => 'window.open(\'' . $this->getTabUrl() . '\',\'_blank\')',
            'class' => 'back'
                ], -1
        );
```

This is working fine in my system. If it's still create an issue then you should at least check in other browser.

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Have you tried in another browser ? Because it's working fine in 2 different system. So I think there must be browser issue or you done some typo mistake :) @Zinat

Comment: Yes, and please remove your duplicate marking in may next question, that's different